# Can't use pipenv after adding to $PATH

Tags: linux, python, path, pip

I'm using a Linux box on which I don't have sudo privileges.  I have python and pip installed.  I've run `pip3 install --user pipenv`, and confirmed that `~/.local/bin/pipenv` exists.  I then added `PATH=~/.local/bin/:${PATH}` to my profile, and sourced it.  `echo $PATH` shows that this worked.  But then running `pipenv` still showed "command not found."

Did I miss a step?  I should be able to do this, right?

Answer (score 0):

In place of `PATH=~/.blahblah` I had written out `~` directly.  And incorrectly.  When I used my actual home directory it worked.